# How to create a empty Array using Mybatis and PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jdbc, mybatis

when I writing my project using Mybatis and Postgres, something disgusting happened.

You know that Postgres has a wonderful type `ARRAY`, but the only way creating a `java.sql.Array` is `java.sql.Connection:createOf(typeName, arrayContent)`, here is the background.

To build a relationship between List and ARRAY, I wrote the `TypeHandler` following:

```
@MappedTypes(List.class)
@MappedJdbcTypes({JdbcType.ARRAY})
public class ListTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<List> {
 private static final String TYPE_NAME_UUID = "uuid";

 @Override
 public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, List list, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
   Connection conn = ps.getConnection();

   if(list.size() != 0) {
     Object[] parameter = list.toArray(new Object[0]);
     String typeName = null;
     // using a switch to determine how to map the Java type to the sql type
     if (list.get(0) instanceof UUID) {
       typeName = TYPE_NAME_UUID;
     }

     if (typeName == null) {
       throw new TypeException("ArrayTypeHandler parameter typeName error, your type is " + parameter.getClass().getName());
     }
     Array array = conn.createArrayOf(typeName, parameter);
     ps.setArray(i, array);
   } else {
     // here is the hard point
     ps.setArray(i, conn.createArrayOf("uuid", new Object[0]));
   }
 }

 private List getArray(Array array) {
   try {
     return Arrays.asList((Object[])array.getArray());
   } catch (Exception e) {
     return null;
   }

 }
}
```

Because there is no type in `java.sql.Array` neither in List (because of the fxcking erasing), and there are lots of arrays with different types in my database, so I have to make a unified `TypeHandler` to deal with `Array` and `List` relationship.

My solution is to take the first object of the List and see what the type is, then map it to the database-favored type. Evertthing seems fine.

But when a empty List goes in, all the things mess up. Firstly, I cannot determine the type based on the first element; secondly, I cannot get the type infomation with List object (curse type erasure again); thirdly, I cannot get the sql type with `sql.Array` Object; forthly, I cannot create a empty `sql.Array` independent of the type (in my opinion, if a pass a empty array to database, the database should create it based on what the type it catually is...). So in a word, I am stucked...

I wonder maybody can help me out? i am SOOOOOOOO DADDDDDDDD.....

PLEASE Orz....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my purposes I map arrays to `Set` and it works very good with `PreparedStatement.setObject` and you can as an option for empty list do the following:

```
if (list.isEmpty()) {
   ps.setObject(i, Collections.<Object>emptySet());
} else {
   //process non-empty list
}
```